# Why isn't the second editor of any question notified of the previous edits once it has been saved?

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits

I edited a question and saved it. It happened to be that there was another person who suggested an edit before me and removed the word **"Thanks"** from the post. When I saved mine, I did not remove the word "Thanks". After a while the first editor commented with an @ reference to me saying that I was responsible for adding back the "Thanks" and I shouldn't be doing it because he removed it! Am not sure if this is some kind of a bug to be taken care of?

Comment: *"Although i raised a flag to his message that it was offensive"* **[Don't do that](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/offensive)**.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta  Why wouldn't you?  We can't see the comment, so we can't really comment on the comment...  It might have been quite rude.

Comment: I'm thinking that Gayu would have called that out, were that the case, @Seth.

Comment: Here's a question. Why didn't _you_ remove the Thanks?

Comment: @ColeJohnson Not everyone agrees that "Thanks" should be removed.  It's sometimes a matter of personal preference, though I usually remove it myself.  Your standards aren't always everyone else's...  BTW, do we have any edit standards anywhere?

Comment: @Seth http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta - i raised a flag because that person's message was "Gayu you don't add thanks to a post and not especially when i removed it". After i replied to him saying that i didn't do it he was still accusing. I felt it was a bit offensive because i was not responsible for that!!! Like Seth says i always feel saying thanks in advance is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Well, I don't know what "still accusing" means, Gayu, but don't be surprised if your flag is declined. "Offensive" means something more severe than that.

Comment: I assume we're talking about [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676618/objective-c-syntax-help-literals#comment22254282_15676618)?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta - yes we are talking about this question :) but since i saw a "-1" on the question i just wanted to clarify.

Comment: @Seth - i have seen messages saying "this edit would be only saved if it was better then the previous one" but when we try to edit is it the original post or the already edited one? And i always do not see the "an edit has been made;click to load" as you mentioned below.

Comment: @Gayu Like I mentioned, it didn't happen this time because you both submitted your edits at (almost) the same time.

Comment: @Seth - i understand but i have edited around 20 questions and i never saw that message. Does it mean am always submitting with others at the same time?

Comment: @Gayu If you don't see that message most likely your edit went through just fine.  Although in some cases your edit may conflict (like this one).

Comment: @Seth - If i edit went through fine how come i do not see my name under the "Edited by" in the post?. I only see the other person's name. Does it mean that person finished editing after me so mine was overwritten?

Comment: @Gayu Do you have a link to the question?  It's hard to tell without seeing.

Comment: @Seth - i edited the following question and i think it went through because i got +2 reputations for it. If the other person edited it finally how come i get reputation points for it?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739121/error-message-while-running-statically-linked-occi-application-on-11g

Comment: @Gayu  Your name is there, see [the revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15739121/revisions).  Your name only appears on the question until *someone else* edits, and then their name is on the question.  All edits and editors can be seen in the revision history however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It isn't a bug, it's a feature!

Just kidding.  On the serious side, I'm not sure this *can* be done.

When you submitted your edit it conflicted with the other users edit making it look like you added the "Thanks" back in.

This can only happen if you both click the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button at (almost) the same time.  Otherwise the system applies your update *over* the earlier edit, only keeping changes that *he* didn't change or the system rejects your edit altogether if you didn't change as much as the other editor.

As to your title, the editor *is* notified when someone else submits an edit:

[image]

Although in your case you weren't notified because both of you submitted an edit at the same time, causing this problem.